# NavigationViewControllers in ipad applications

Tags: iphone, ipad

Are NavigationViewControllers as relevant in ipad applications as in iphone apps, or are they less relevant as the window has place for multiple elements and not strictly a stack?

Answer (score 1):

i assume you are speaking of UINavigationControllers and using UITableViewControllers with them. To answer that question: They are still often used as the master view controller (the left pane in landscape, or the popover in portrait.  This allows flattening your view hierarchy but still maintaining the navigation ability of the stack.

For more information about the iPad human interface guidelines see here : [Apple iPad HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)